# Perl: Parse file and concatenate strings if two consecutive lines start by OS

Tags: perl, parsing

I have to parse a UniProt file looking like this:

```
ID   001R_FRG3G              Reviewed;         256 AA.
AC   ERPL_ADA;
OS   Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3).
ID   002L_FRG3G              Reviewed;         320 AA.
AC   Q6GZX3;
OS   Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3 / ADD / PERM /
OS   strain HB).
```

and so on.

I want to retrieve all OS identifiers (species), but the case is that some of them have unique OS, and some others have duplicated OS in consecutive lines, which I should concatenate.

So that the output would be:

```
OS Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3).
OS Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) (FV-3 / ADD / PERM / strain HB).
```

For one OS occurrence I can select the line using regexp like:

```
while ($line=<IN>){

    chomp $line; 

    if ($line=~ /^OS\s{3}/ and $line=~ /\.$/){

               $os= $line;

    }

  }
```

But how to do when you have two consecutive OS? I have been trying adding a next but I could not reach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @species;
while (1) {
   my $line = <$IN>;

   if (defined($line)) {
      chomp($line);
      my @fields = split(' ', $_, 2);
      if ($fields[0] eq 'OS') {
         push @species, $fields[2];
      }
   }

   if (@species) {
      say join ' ', @species;
      @species = ();
   }

   last if !defined($line);
}
```